# What's the difference between "bring about" and "implement"?

Tags: meaning

In my English workbook there is an exercise to match words with their description.
I'm confused by the following match that've been made by the authors (I checked it in answers section):

```
implement - make something that has been decided start to happen

bring about - make something happen
```

There are examples: implement a change, bring about change.

As for me, implementation sounds more like a whole process from beginning to the end, so I opted for the opposite match.

So could someone please dispel my doubts and explain the difference? Would you agree with such descriptions of the words?

Comment: The two definitions are not the same. How can we tell what "matches" what? You don't provide any information about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bring about** is broader, meaning

> cause to happen
>
> *One way they can bring about political change is by putting pressure on the country.*

{[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bring-about)}

The agent, as here, may be volitional, but natural causes are equally possible:

> The first rain in months brought about mudslides when it hit [areas]
>   that were scorched by ... December's large wildfires.

..............

**Implement** needs a volitional agent, as it means

> put into practical effect; carry out: *implement the new procedures*
>   {[AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/implement)}

...

> carry out; put into action; perform: *implement a plan*
>   {[Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/implement)}

There needs to be a plan / set of rules already in existence, which are put into effect (implemented).

..............

'Change' works with either verb, as it may but need not imply a pre-existing goal.

........................................

**regarding telicity**

[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bring-about) does not insist that *bring about* obligatorily refers to a completed effect. Though it gives

> *bring about*
>
> to make something happen, especially to cause changes in a situation

it adds the possibility of an inchoative rather than a telic interpretation:

> related words: to make something start to exist or happen: ... trigger
>   ...

.............

For *implement*, [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/implement) seems only to license a telic (completed change) usage:

> *implement* verb [*with object*]
>
> Put (a decision, plan, agreement, etc.) into effect.

though [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/implement) seems to add an inchoative licensing

> to start using a plan or system: *The changes to the national health
>   system will be implemented next year.*

So while 'implementation means a whole process from beginning to end, a done deal, the completed transformation' (which goes beyond what you're saying) bears thinking about, it is over-prescriptive. I'd say 'bring about' is at least as telically orientated.

Comment: 'Change' works with either verb - what will be a case when one should be preferred over the other? I can't catch the subtle difference in meaning when the words are put in the same sentence.

Comment: 'The ice ages brought about vast changes in the geology of the area' / 'We need to implement these [proposed] changes without further delay'.

Comment: Couldn't it be said: We need to bring about these [proposed] changes without further delay'?

Comment: Not if they're changes to the law, say. Use 'We need to implement these newly made changes to the law without further delay' as an unequivocal example. // But  I realise that I haven't addressed telicity (related to whether 'implementation sounds more like [it involves] a whole process from beginning to the end' is correct), so I'll add this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**bring about : His greed for power brought about the war.**
: the reason for the war resulted from his greed.

**implement : The government has decided to implement a new law starting next year.**
: make a new law become effective.

hope you figure it out. :)